# Calculate min/max values for (un)signed integral number of up to 64 bits

Tags: c#

> This question is a follow up of [Calculate min/max values for signed or unsigned integral number with any valid number of bits (up to 64)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/87755/calculate-min-max-values-for-signed-or-unsigned-integral-number-with-any-valid-n)

I was answering the question [Given two int values, return the one closer to 10](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/86754), and I indicated that something like the following snippet of code could be a different approach for solving the problem.

In the original question, it turned out I had made a mistake, but since there were already some answers, I've decided to post a follow up question with the fixes.

Can this be done in a more efficient or more elegant way?

```
public class Bits
{
    public static void MinMaxI(ulong _bits, out long _min, out long _max)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        _min = ~(long)0 << (int)(_bits - 1);
        _max = -1 - _min;
    }


    public static long MinI(ulong _bits)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        return ~(long)0 << (int)(_bits - 1);
    }


    public static long MaxI(ulong _bits)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        return -1 - (~(long)0 << (int)(_bits - 1));
    }


    public static ulong MaxN(ulong _bits)
    {
        // ? unsigned range with at least one value bit
        if (_bits < 1 || _bits > 64)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
             String.Format("1 <= _bits <= 64"));
        }

        return _bits == 64 ? ~(ulong)0 : ~(~(ulong)0 << (int)_bits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would the question title "Calculate min/max values for (un)signed integral number of up to 64 bits" be a good title for your question, you think?

Comment: @Pimgd: that would be a better title. Can I change this without again violating any rules? Or do you have to do it? I didn't write this code in my answer to the other question, it's a different approach to the problem. So your edit is not correct. And the question "Can this be done in a more efficient or more elegant way?" is not allowed, according to Jamal, because it concerns code yet to be written. Perhaps you can give me an answer: what's the purpose of this site if only 100% correct and 100% efficient code may be posted?

Comment: You can edit your own question no problem, it's just that certain actions are prohibited. There's some obvious rules, like no offensive content, but you don't seem to be having trouble with those. What you're getting tripped up by are the rules we slowly defined as a community that serve to keep questions and answers valuable, even after several months or years have past.

Comment: For instance, we require the code to be included in the question, as links may rot. For programming challenges, the problem should be described in the question, as the link may rot. When you have received some answers, you shouldn't change the code in your question anymore, since that would make the question hard to understand/read. Lastly, there's some rules regarding content that's not allowed - we don't review broken code, and we don't implement functions for you.

Comment: So regarding the phrasing "Can this be done in a more efficient or more elegant way?", yeah, it's kinda bad. It's better to have a specific problem in mind - to have an actual question, not just code. "Does my code handle all edge cases?" is a valid question, "Is there a way to reduce duplication in my argument validation" would be another one... What you ask for is what reviewers are likely to focus on. Of course, they're free to review any aspect of the code, but that what you ask for, you're more likely to receive.

Comment: It is not required to have 100% correct and 100% efficient code. If you take a look at the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), section "I'm confused! What questions are on-topic for this site?", you can see that our requirements are like this: "To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?" and "Do I want the code to be good code? (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)", etc. We don't require perfect code - we require code that you're fairly certain of that it works.

Comment: If you have any more questions, I suggest you come to the chat - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor - comments aren't really the appropriate place for this, and I've already swamped your question with my explanation comments (my bad).

Comment: @Pimgd: that explains some things. I had the problem in the other post that I was pretty sure the code worked - but it didn't. So the post was put on hold by Jamal, because the code didn't work. This means you have to post 100% correct code :( And I was not allowed to edit the code to work, which was requested to remove the hold ;) It's a personal matter, but I know code reviews for more than 30 years in professinal software development and they work very different from the rules of this platform - so it's not a place for me to post questions or give answers anymore.

Comment: You might be interested in reading this meta: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5201/how-does-se-code-review-differ-from-a-real-life-code-review - basically, there's a bit of a difference here. We're a pretty big site and receive a few code dumps or just plain broken code here on a daily basis and quickly filter these by closing the question. Sometimes it feels unfair. I think your case should be discussed though, it's not okay if the close message says you can fix the issue and then it turns out you can't.

Comment: @Pimgd: I understand that clearly broken code is not wanted. On the other hand there are lots of people who are not that experienced and just don't see that the code is broken. Or experienced developers, just making stupid mistakes sometimes - like me ;) It's very fair, that you want to discuss this issue, thanks. The answer to the "closer to 10" post took me more than one day of work. So never mind, I'll better work productively instead of helping others.

Comment: It's too bad if you feel that way. But you know, it's perfectly okay. Personally, I rarely spend a full day on an answer like that - I look at a question and if it looks like fun, I'll spend 15 minutes on an answer. You don't have to answer everything in a question, you know? Heck, I'll show you.

Comment: @Pimgd: I didn't want to spend more than a day. But the question got me interested because I remembered that I ran into such edge case problems several times through the years. So I thought, it would be helpful for others to go deeper into the subject and I still think that my answer can be helpful to others in many ways. I like to chat with you because you are very reasonable - thanks for that. But we are violating the rules here, so let's cut it short. Perhaps another place another time - my pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument validation could be de-duplicated.

Here, take a look:

```
MinMaxI:
    if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
         String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
    }

MinI:
    if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
         String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
    }

MaxI:
    if (_bits < 2 || _bits > 64)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
         String.Format("2 <= _bits <= 64"));
    }

MaxN:
    if (_bits < 1 || _bits > 64)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
         String.Format("1 <= _bits <= 64"));
    }
```

They're practically the same!

I'd make a method like this (I'm not really familiar with C# syntax, so let me know if I made a mistake)

```
private static void validateBitsArgument(ulong _bits, ulong min, ulong max)
{
    if (_bits < min || _bits > max)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
         String.Format("{0} <= _bits <= {1}", min, max));
    }
}
```

And then include it like this:

```
public class Bits
{
    public static void MinMaxI(ulong _bits, out long _min, out long _max)
    {
        validateBitsArgument(_bits, 2, 64);

        _min = ~(long)0 << (int)(_bits - 1);
        _max = -1 - _min;
    }


    public static long MinI(ulong _bits)
    {
        validateBitsArgument(_bits, 2, 64);

        return ~(long)0 << (int)(_bits - 1);
    }


    public static long MaxI(ulong _bits)
    {
        validateBitsArgument(_bits, 2, 64);

        return -1 - (~(long)0 << (int)(_bits - 1));
    }


    public static ulong MaxN(ulong _bits)
    {
        validateBitsArgument(_bits, 1, 64);

        return _bits == 64 ? ~(ulong)0 : ~(~(ulong)0 << (int)_bits);
    }

    private static void validateBitsArgument(ulong _bits, ulong min, ulong max)
    {
        if (_bits < min || _bits > max)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException("_bits", _bits,
         String.Format("{0} <= _bits <= {1}", min, max));
        }
    }
}
```

And voila, shorter code.

Comment: Answer written in 6-7 minutes - just a quick review of something that I spotted... and partially to demonstrate that it doesn't take a huge amount of time to help someone out if you can see something they don't.

Comment: And that's a really good one! The only thing to consider is, that an additional function call is more expensive than the code duplication. So perhaps an even better way would be a preprocessor macro?

Comment: @carpetemporem Perhaps, but if you go that way you should ditch the `String.Format` call too - just put the numbers straight in there.

Comment: @carpetemporem - and C# has a JIT compiler that can inline functions, so you might not need to do it manually anyways.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - and there's always the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AgressiveInlining)]` attribute if the JIT doesn't figure it out.

Comment: My mistake: I mixed up the C# preprocessor with the C/C++ preprocessor. AFAIK, the C# preprocessor only offers definition of symbols but no macros. So the function without the second argument (which is always `64`) is the way to go.